# Fragments Implement OnClickListener

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, fragment

I have this Fragments but i cant findviewbyid. i already look around website but get nothing. thankss

```
public class Course extends Fragment implements OnClickListener

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.course, container, false);
    View button1Button = findViewById(R.id.button_button1);
    button1Button.setOnClickListener(this);
    View button2Button = findViewById(R.id.button_button2);
    button2Button.setOnClickListener(this);
    View button3Button = findViewById(R.id.button_button3);
    button3Button.setOnClickListener(this);
    View button4Button = findViewById(R.id.button_button4);
    button4Button.setOnClickListener(this);
    View button5Button = findViewById(R.id.button_button5);
    button5Button.setOnClickListener(this);
    View button6Button = findViewById(R.id.button_button6);
    button6Button.setOnClickListener(this);
    View button7Button = findViewById(R.id.button_button7);
    button7Button.setOnClickListener(this);
    View button8Button = findViewById(R.id.button_button8);
    button8Button.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

thankss

Comment: use view.findViewById

Answer (score 0):

Fragment does not have method `findViewById()`, instead use the layout you are inflating.

change

`View button1Button = findViewById(R.id.button_button1);`

to

```
View button1Button = view.findViewById(R.id.button_button1);
```

and all other assignments.

Answer (score 0):

Just do following change. It should work after that.

```
Button button8Button = view.findViewById(R.id.button_button8);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, you need to call `findViewById` on the inflated `view`:

`View button1Button = view.findViewById(R.id.button_button1);`

Don't forget to return your `view` variable at the end of the method.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this.

```
public class Course extends Fragment implements OnClickListener

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.course, container, false);
        View button1Button = view.findViewById(R.id.button_button1);
        button1Button.setOnClickListener(this);
        //Other buttons go here

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to this hope this can help you..

```
 public class Course extends Fragment implements OnClickListener

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.course, container, false);
    Button button1Button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_button1);
    button1Button.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button button2Button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_button2);
    button2Button.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button button3Button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_button3);
    button3Button.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button button4Button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_button4);
    button4Button.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button button5Button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_button5);
    button5Button.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button button6Button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_button6);
    button6Button.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button button7Button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_button7);
    button7Button.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button button8Button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_button8);
    button8Button.setOnClickListener(this);
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `View` in front of **OnClickListener** to `View.OnClickListener`.
2. Add `view` in front of **findViewById** to `view.findViewById`.

try this:

```
    public class Course extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.course, container, false);
        View button1 = view.findViewById(R.id.button_button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
     }
      ....
}
```